# PHP: passing a variable through a link

Tags: php, html, variables, get

```
echo '<td><a href="pagetwo.php?id="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

I need to send the `$row['id']` to pagetwo.php

it pretty much has to be this way (as far as i know) as 
page one is a list of links... basicly... page two being where I actualy work with the data
however the data on page two is called for by the same id found in `$row['id']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

page1.php

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="page2.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```